# Read SQL query file from project directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've put 3 especially large SQL queries within my Visual Studio project, under a folder "Queries" that is in the project directory (not the solution). Is there an eloquent way to access these files? I was hoping that something like `@"Queries/firstSqlQuery.sql` would work.

Specifying the full path, like with `@"C:\\Users\John\Documents\VisualStudio2010\Projects\MySolution\MyProject\Queries\firstSqlQuery.sql`
is something I'd really rather not do, since it requires me to go back into code and fix the path, should the application move.

EDIT: For some reason, the page is looking for the files in `C:\\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\Queries\firstSqlQuery.sql`. Why is it looking in this location, when the executable directory is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this... if it's outside of project. (When I intitially read this-- I misread and thought it was in the solution directory which I was assuming contained the project)--

```
var pathToBin = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var directoryInfoOfBin = new DirectoryInfo(pathToBin);
var solutionDirectory = directory.Parent().Parent();
var pathToSolution = solutionDirectory.FullName;
```

but this is much simpler if it's in the project

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Queries/firstSqlQuery");
```

Comment: Server.MapPath was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to handle this, but there is a fundamental understanding you must gather first. Issuing something like `@"Queries/..."` isn't, by itself, isn't going to do anything. You need to leverage the `System.IO` namespace to perform IO operations.

With that part of the foundation, let's lay some more, when you issue a command like this:

```
File.ReadAllText("firstSqlQuery.sql");
```

the path that is implied is the `Working Directory` of the assembly that's executing the code. When debugging an application in Visual Studio, especially and ASP.NET Application, that's the `bin` directory that resides under the project directory, **by default**. So, if you did want to access the `Queries` folder, you would have to do something like this:

```
File.ReadAllText(@"..\Queries\firstSqlQuery.sql");
```

so, that's one way of handling it.

Another way of handling it would be to copy the file over into the `bin` folder every time the project is built by looking at the file properties (e.g. create a `Post Build Event`), but that's more work than I think you're looking for.

Again, the key here is to understand **what directory you're starting in.**

Finally, one thing worth noting, if you leverage the directory structure you'll need to ensure that the `Queries` folder gets deployed to the live site. That probably goes without saying, but I've seen people run into that exact problem before.

Comment: Yep, I've been using `System.IO`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure your query files are copy to the output directory when you do a build and read the files from there without having to set a path.

Comment: One of the first settings I enabled. Check my edit: the application is looking in a weird location.

Comment: @rwhite, You should be able to right click the query file in solution explore and select properties. On the properties menu set "Copy to Output directory" to "Copy always"

Comment: Yep, that's one of the first settings I enabled!